# Oracle SQL: Is it more efficient to use a WHERE clause in a subquery or after the join?

Tags: sql, oracle

I wanted to know which would be more efficient and why:

example 1:

```
    SELECT a.CUSTOMER_KEY a.LAST_NAME b.TRASACTION_AMT, 
    FROM CUSTOMER_TABLE a 
    LEFT JOIN TRANSACTION_TABLE b 
    ON a.CUSTOMER_KEY = b.CUSTOMER_KEY
    WHERE b.DATE_TRANSACTION > 20150101 AND a.CUSTOMER_ACTIVE_FLAG = 'Y';
```

or example 2:

```
    SELECT a.CUSTOMER_KEY a.LAST_NAME b.TRASACTION_AMT, 
    FROM 
        (SELECT * 
        FROM CUSTOMER_TABLE 
        WHERE CUSTOMER_ACTIVE_FLAG = 'Y') a 
    LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT * 
        FROM TRANSACTION_TABLE 
        WHERE b.DATE_TRANSACTION > 20150101) b 
    ON a.CUSTOMER_KEY = b.CUSTOMER_KEY
```

For instance would option 2 be better optimized because it would filter out the records not satisfying the where clause first?

(NOTE: the query looks to join customer information with transaction information based on customer key. The customer key is unique to the customer table. Both querys produce equivalent output.)

Comment: These are not logically equivalent queries.  If you had a customer without a transaction that meets the date filter, the second query would return a row for that customer, with no transaction amount, while the first query would not return a row for that customer at all.  In the first query, by putting the `b` condition in the WHERE clause, you have effectively changed the outer join into an inner join.

Comment: Are you asking only about this specific query, or for queries in general as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct equivalent query without a `join` is:

```
SELECT a.CUSTOMER_KEY a.LAST_NAME b.TRASACTION_AMT, 
FROM CUSTOMER_TABLE a LEFT JOIN 
     TRANSACTION_TABLE b 
      ON a.CUSTOMER_KEY = b.CUSTOMER_KEY AND b.DATE_TRANSACTION > 20150101
WHERE a.CUSTOMER_ACTIVE_FLAG = 'Y';
```

The condition on the second table goes in the `ON` clause.

The best way to know is to look at the execution plans and run-times for the two queries.  I would expect the equivalent versions to have the same execution plan.  Oracle has a smart optimizer and should optimize away the subqueries.  However, it might miss a particular case or two, which is why you should check on your own queries.

Comment: Why does the condition on the second transaction go in the ON clause? I haven't heard of this before. The way it was written by the OP is legal. What's the difference?

Comment: @mathguy - Because this is an outer join, putting that condition in a WHERE clause would have a different meaning than putting it in the ON clause.  Both are legal constructs, but they would potentially produce different results (depending on the actual data).

Comment: Oh, I got it - thanks! I didn't pay attention to the "correct equivalent of the other query" part in Gordon's post either.